# Text is the cvitem is shifted down to the bottom when using multicols

Tags: moderncv, cv

I have the following code shown below:

```
\section{\textbf{Apple}}

\cvitem{Testing}{
  \begin{itemize}
 \begin{multicols}{3}
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C
  \item D
  \item E
 \end{multicols}
  \end{itemize}
}
```

The problem is that cvitem text is shifted down to the bottom when using multicols. Is there a way to get the "Testing" to the top and not the bottom?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To print cv items in two columns, you can use the `\cvdoubleitem` command as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\name{John}{Doe}
\begin{document}

\section{Section heading}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\end{document}
```

[image]